# How do I extract ValueTuple data with NpgsqlDataReader

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, valuetuple

I'm using NpgsqlDataReader to extract data from a PostgreSQL database in C#.

My PostgreSQL table has a column of the **cidr** data type.

In C# when I use the NpgsqlDataReader's `.GetFieldType(index).ToString();` method, I get the following:
**System.ValueTuple`2[System.Net.IPAddress,System.Int32]**

I have the NuGet System.ValueTuple package installed in my project.

Does NpgsqlDataReader have a method to access the data?

Comment: Does `.GetFieldValue<(IPAddress, int)>(index)` work?

Comment: Which version of `NpgsqlDataReader` are you using (from nuget?)

Comment: @Steeeve I'm using Npgsql 4.0.12